# How to fire ValidateOninput for blazor component Text box

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

This I My common Razor Component

```
[CommomTextBoxComponent.razor]
<SfTextBox Placeholder="@Placeholder" @bind-Value="@BindingValue" Type="@InputType" ValidateOnInput="true" Autocomplete="AutoComplete.Off" FloatLabelType="FloatLabelType.Always" CssClass="@CssClass" ShowClearButton="true" maxlength="@MaxLength" minlength="@MinLength" />

@code{
       private string _value;

       [Parameter]
       public string BindingValue
       {
           get => _value;
           set
           {
               if (_value == value) return;
               _value = value;
               BindingValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
           }
       }

       [Parameter]
       public EventCallback<string> BindingValueChanged { get; set; }

       [Parameter]
       public InputType InputType { get; set; }

       [Parameter]
       public static string CssClass { get; set; }

       [Parameter]
       public static bool Validate { get; set; }

       [Parameter]
       public string Placeholder { get; set; }

       [Parameter]
       public int MaxLength { get; set; }

       [Parameter]
       public int MinLength { get; set; }
}
```

This is my razor page code

```
@page "/"

<CommonInputTextBox Placeholder="Login ID" @bind-BindingValue="m1.Login_User" MinLength="5" MaxLength="12" />
```

**By defaut Syncfusion component supports Oninputvalidate after making it as a common it stopped working
Pl see the compononent code i have made it true still its not working**

So please Help me to validate text box on input

**Thanks In Advance**

Comment: Q1 - Are you using your `CommonInputTextBox` within an `EditForm` context?  Q2 - Why are you wrapping the `SfTextBox` inside a wrapper that just sets the values on the `SfTextBox`.

Comment: Yes made it as a commom component passing parametes and i use them in editform sorry i didnt mentioned....i am warpping cuz i have lot of text boxed in my applcation and lot of people are working so its better to pass parameters...                                                           

if you have any good solution for validateoninput pl share with me

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you're binding to a local value, not the `EditForm` Model/EditContext.  You need to set up and bind the bind parameters individually.

I don't use Syncfusion, but I'm guessing the setup is not different than for a standard `InputBase` control.

Here's a basic setup using `InputText`

My component - `TextInput.razor`

```
@using System.Linq.Expressions;

<InputText Value="@this.Value" ValueChanged="this.ValueChanged" ValueExpression="this.ValueExpression"  />

@code {
    [Parameter]public string? Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<string>>? ValueExpression { get; set; }
}
```

And a Test Page:

```
@page "/Test"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<h3>Test</h3>

<div>
    <EditForm Model="model">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <TextInput @bind-Value=this.model.Title />
        <ValidationSummary />
    </EditForm>
</div>

@code {
    private Model model = new Model();

    public class Model
    {
        [Required]
        public string? Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Reply...

Its not validating on Oninput or OnKeypress event